# WSO2 Identity server not returning errors in login

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity Server V 5.3.0. I am calling login operation in AuthenticationAdmin Service.

When the user is unlocked, it just returns false where as in the logs it prints User is unlocked.

How to know whether the user is locked or unlocked and send that as a response for login operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't remmeber the exact name of the Admin service. But there is a one adminservice where you can check the claim values of a particular claim. SO what you need to do is call that admin service and check for the isLocked claim value of the user. AFAIR service for RemoteUserStoreManager service. Check more information on https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Locking+a+Specific+User+Account